# Does dissociative amnesia bring any evolutive advantage?

Tags: evolution, evolutionary-psychology, amnesia, dissociation

Dissociative amnesia may appear after you have experienced a threat where you are unable to produce either fight or flight response.

Can we ascribe any evolutive advantage to this course of events or is it just nothing more than a case of brain failure?